# Function call not returning variable value despite being filled in called function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What is wrong with this code?

```
function testGetConstants () {
  var arrayConstants = [];  
  getConstants( arrayConstants );
};

function getConstants ( arrayConstants ) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1oh9OY5ssUt9pg1VGPCrocyd7SjT1DyjgNxIS9xmmSrf');
  var namesSheet = ss.getSheetByName('TheConstants');    
  var metadatenConstants = namesSheet.getRange('Constants');
  
  arrayConstants = metadatenConstants.getValues();
  return arrayConstants;
};
```

Before the statement

```
return arrayConstants;
```

arrayConstants is populated, but inside testGetConstants it is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the `getConstants()` but the return value is not assigned anywhere.

You can try assigning `getConstants( arrayConstants );` to `arrayConstants` inside `testGetConstants()`. It should look like this:

```
function testGetConstants () {
  var arrayConstants = [];  
  arrayConstants = getConstants( arrayConstants );
};
```

Please let me know if this works.